# Fetch data with SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a page which has query parameters and my data is fetching using SSR. Whenever my query parameters change (and it changes quite fast), data is fetched again with SSR (no client side data fetching).

Is it okay to fetch data like that **OR** should I combine it with client side data fetching ( I mean first time I pre-render and fetch data with SSR and after that I should user client side data fetching). If second option, please, can you provide some resources or answers how I can do that.

Comment: Hey @Andrii, what do you mean by your query parameters changing fast? Do I understand it correctly that your page stays the same but just the query params change?

Comment: @Skocdopole yep you're right, my query parameters are changing every time user changes input and then they are used to search for data. The page stays the same. But this page is needed to be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to rendering a page and then updating its content often, let's say upon user interaction, SSR is best used only on the initial navigation, and the subsequent content fetches are done client-side.

On the first glance it's logical. SSR's primary goal is to make the first interaction with a new page seamless, be it for bots or users - it presents complete markup to crawlers and makes the page load faster (or makes it look faster) to users. But if you would use SSR for the subsequent updates as well, it would be a waste of bytes by sending the full HTML over the wire and letting the server generate the markup all the time and would result in a worse UX.

So to combine both approaches, you can do something like:

```js
export default class Page extends React.Component<Props> {
  static async getInitialProps({ query }: NextPageContext) {
    const data = await fetchYourData(query.yourParam);
    return { data };
  }
 
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return <main>Your data: {data}</main>;
  }
}
```

The key is using [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-initial-props). That method will first run server-side and on subsequent navigations to the same route, but with different search params, will run client-side.

---

Of course there are few caveats. First of all, do you even need SSR? Often, pages heavily customized by search params are not indexed (imagine product search page), which eliminates one of the big arguments for SSR.

PS: This is not relevant to your example in next.js, but I'll put it out there anyway, you can theoretically perform SSR only for the part of the page that needs to be updated. Remix.js [is capable of doing just that](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.16.0/guides/data-loading#remix-optimizations) by sending the partial markup together with some metadata over HTTP which then gets applied just to the relevant section of the page.

Comment: Thank you, I found your answer useful, so as I got fetch data with only SSR will take more time and resources than client side data fetching, yep?

Comment: There isn't a simple answer. If we take the remix.js example with only partial SSR update, I can easily imagine a scenario where it is faster than client-side data fetch with UI update (eg. for slower mobile phones). You'd have to compare and experiment a bit. 

But if we are talking SSR that next.js offers - always sending the full HTML over the wire when page is requested - it probably returns much larger response than a simple JSON data fetch, and client-side fetch is probably easier to implement here as well.